# I see all aliases besides the home page alias (At URL bar)

Tags: path-aliases

Why is that? I mean, why when I click the home page link at main menu, it is only the site's URL (www.example.com), and not the exact URL of the home page (www.example.com/Decorations-for-all-houses) that appears? how can I make the full URL appear at the home page?

It should be noted that this is the only page with this problem; in all other pages, the FULL URL is always displayed.

Comment: Why do you need the full URL to appear? As long as you've got an appropriate canonical meta tag there shouldn't be a problem

Comment: I went ahead and deleted your other question.  Next time, just update the original instead of posting new quetions.  Thanks, and welcome to Drupal Answers!

Comment: Your issue is by design as well. The home page you set in Configuration > Site Information is what will show for base URL.

Comment: @clive is it possible to display the full, if so how then? :)

Comment: @Bala Anything's possible :) Some combination of pathauto, global redirect and setting a canonical somewhere should do the trick. I've never actually tried to do it to be honest

Comment: I tried to create an alternative alias. there is a chance it worked for me once, but it might not and I'm wrong. 

Any concrete ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you set your site home page "Decorations-for-all-houses" (or perhaps lowercase would be less confusing) at admin/config/system/site-information, any home link provided by core, contrib modules, themes etc. will point to the right page.

You can edit any link of your main-menu including the home link at admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu. The default link for home is <front>
which will point to your assigned home page, but it can be any path, including "decorations-for-all-houses".

Themes typically implement their logo link so that it points to the home page without the path, so you would have to edit the theme.

The above (hopefully) covers any case where users already on your site click a home link or logo. But what about visitors clicking a link outside of your site, like Google, or typing the domain name? For redirecting them from www.example.com to www.example.com/decorations-for-all-houses something like the Global redirect module probably would be able to do that.

What people usually seem to want, is just the opposite, redirect from the long url to the root. It might be confusing to visitors if they never can't get to the www.example.com even if they want to. This is what visitors expect to see as the home page url.

Comment: "Decorations-for-all-houses"?

You mean, just write this input at the "Default front page" field?

Comment: Sure. Actual path (node/123) or alias (Decorations-for-all-houses), doesn't matter which, the alias will always used anyway.