# Display the full URL of the home page?

Tags: 7, uri

Is it possible to display the full, absolute URL of the home page in Drupal 7, like  www.example.com/The-best-example-possible ?

I'd like to display the full URL of the home page, not just the hostname.

Comment: are you asking if it's possible to change the location of the home page from example.com/something to example.com/somethingelse? Or do you wan the browser's url bar to display example.com/home when on the home screen?

Comment: @Jance Yes, i want that the full URL will be displayed also at the homepage.

Comment: Where do you want to display the URL? Can you make your question a bit clearer?

Comment: @benosika Is this the same problem as http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85838/i-see-all-aliases-besides-the-home-page-alias-at-url-bar ?

Answer (score 5):

In Drupal 7, The front page is normally set via [`system_site_information_settings()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.admin.inc/function/system_site_information_settings/7).  It is an unaliased URL, so it is best to use the API.  I would do it as:

```
$home = url(variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node'), array('absolute' => TRUE));
```

In Drupal 8, there is a special route `<front>` that you can use with the [`Url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.6.x) object

```
use \Drupal\Core\Url;

$home = Url::fromRoute('<front>')->setAbsolute()->toString();
```

However, in most circumstances you don't need to explicitly render out `Url()` objects as strings; you can just use the object itself.

Comment: Mine's not wrong, but this is much better.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm confused. i don't understand what answer is preferable. what file should i go and what exactly do you think i should change there, please help me understand you. Thanks again, very much indeed !

Comment: If I understand correctly the answers given here has to do with View-based Front-pages. that's not my issue. I ask only about a Node-based Front-Page.

Comment: @benosika Both of these will work with any page set to be the front, not just views pages (I tested with a plain node page).

Comment: @mpdonadio how would you do this in d8?

Answer (score 2):

```
global $conf, $base_url;
echo $base_url . '/' . variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node');
```

For details, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7 and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate with some words here? should I first make the changes at the first file and only than the other?

I couldn't find the files in my D7 directory, not with search even, could you give directions?

Thanks.

Comment: Both of these techniques can be used either in a block, form, even the template. They're not files, this is PHP code. To learn how to make adjustments to the theme, see https://drupal.org/documentation/theme