# How can one display the FULL URL of his homepage?

Tags: 7, uri

I have already asked the question and got too much of a short answer, which didn't allow me to actually solve the problem. I'm sure that elaboration is needed, so more users could enjoy an answer. The question:

Is it possible to display the **full** URL of the home page in Drupal **7**, like:

```
www.example.com/The-best-example-possible
```

I'd like to display the full URL of the home page as displayed above, and not only the **Pure** URL which in this case is:

```
www.example.com
```

How can that be achieved? what file\s should i go for doing that, where can such file\s be found?, what exactly to change, etc.

**Thank you !**

Comment: This is actually the third time you've asked the same question. What's going on here? Here's my answer to one of your previous questions http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/85857/7641 You need to try to explain with more details what it is that you want to achieve instead of repeating the same question over and over.

Comment: Hello, I have explained it very well above, I invite you to read what i wrote above, and I'm sure you will understand very well what i so dearly want to achieve already.

Comment: Please look at the answers and comments on your other two (linked) questions and try to explain there why they didn't solve your problem.

Comment: Sure. These comments allegedly have to do with D6 & D7 Views module. I don't use that module at all and my Front-Page is totally Node-based. therefor, i need another manipulation.

Comment: You should comment the answers you have got on those two pages, not on this page. Nobody is going to answer you on this page because this is actually the fourth version of the same question (one has been deleted). OK?

Comment: I would suggest the delete first two. it seems that people didn't understand what i meant. i will gladly replay at the earlier thread. Thanks.

Comment: I give up. Sorry.